# JQuery Masonry floating text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

Hi I want to float text on the right and left of the Image, but when I use float inside masonry item, **next** masonry items are placed in next row, not beside. Even when there is a place for them to fit.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="masonryItem">
        <div class="accent"></div>
        <div class="header" >TITLE
            <div>
                <div class="imageBox" style="float:left">
                    <div class="imageInn">
                        <img src="images/image.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hoverImg">
                        <img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:252px; height:162px; margin-left:34px; margin-top:86px; text-align:left; margin-right:70px;">
                    TITLE

                    Description
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="masonryItem">
         <div>
             <div class="imageBox" style="margin-bottom:40px">
                 <div class="imageInn">
                     <img src="images/image.png">
                 </div>
                 <div class="hoverImg">
                     <img>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div style="margin-left:40px; text-align:left;">
                 TITLE

                 DESCRIPTION
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:
    .container {
        margin-top:86px; 
        margin-left:53px; 
    }

```
.imageBox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.imageBox .hoverImg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.hoverImg img {
    content: url(images/hover.png);
}

.imageBox:hover .hoverImg {
    display: block;
}

.accent {
    width:6px; 
    height:184px; 
    background:#000; 
    float:left;
}

.header {
    margin-top:14px; 
    margin-left:42px;
    font-size:23px;
}
```

And my JS:

```
var $container = $('.container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.masonryItem'
    });
});
```

Comment: I know that I should avoid using style tag, but it is easier for me to work this way. During cleanup I will place everything in css file :)

Comment: Call  $(".masonryItem").masonry();